# Panopoly add content panel

Tags: panels

I have seen this Panel on Panopoly distribution where you can add different elements from the left side, add content to them and also have a preview.

I was wondering if this is powered by Panel (or its related contributed modules) or is only available if you install Panopoly?

[image]

Many thanks,

Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested installing panopoly distribution and a series of module needed to build same functionality on standard drupal profile installation

Here are my findings

- The functionality you are asking does not seem to achieve with one contrib module instead its a result of lots of modules
- Check this
  [link](https://drupal.org/node/1679838). This links lists the feature list or the main modules
  list.
- lets take [panopoly_pages](https://drupal.org/project/panopoly_pages) contrib module, this module
  allows user to add content or landing page
- but again this module
  depends on several other modules to work in desired way
- Here is
  the [link](https://drupal.org/node/1717680) for complete list of all required modules.

  **My findings**
- Installing all required modules I found it almost become the complete panopoly profile,so in my views it will be better to use panopoly distribution instead of separately installing the modules

How you can add this to existing site ?

- https://drupal.org/node/1717728

Check out more on panopoly [here.](http://prezi.com/0l_derrjnmbx/introduction-to-panopoly/)